# ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: json, angular5

I am working with Angular5.
I have implemented the following code to send data as json to api, please see below

in xxxx.component.ts

```
submitProfileData() {
           let registrationsData = [];
           for (let i = 0; i < this.profileModel.registrationData.length; i++ ) {
            registrationsData.push(
                {
                    id: this.profileModel.registrationData[i].id,
                    registration_number: this.profileModel.registrationData[i].regNo
                });
           }
           const primary_details = {
            street_line1: this.profileEditForm.controls.streetLine1.get('line1').value,
            street_line2: this.profileEditForm.controls.streetLine2.get('line2').value,
            country: this.profileEditForm.controls.countryName.get('country').value,
            state: this.profileEditForm.controls.stateName.get('state').value,
            };
           const profile_details = {
            name: this.profileEditForm.controls.branchName.get('name').value,
            tradingname: this.profileEditForm.controls.tradingName.get('trname').value,
            acronym: this.profileModel.acronym,
            timezone: this.profileEditForm.controls.timeZone,
            registrations: registrationsData
            };
            this.profileEditService
            .editProfileData({primary_details: primary_details, profile_details: profile_details}, this.branchId)
            .subscribe(suc => console.log('response', suc));

    }
```

in xxxxx.service.ts

```
editProfileData(data, branchId) {
        console.log('request data', data);
        return this.http.post(this.config.STORE_KEY + '/public/api/business/changerequest/' + 
                 this.userDetails.roleid + '/' + branchId, data)
                 .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                 .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

41 line console is printing on chrome console. but i am getting the following error

```
ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Request.webpackJsonp.../../../http/@angular/http.es5.js.Body.text (http.es5.js:839)
    at Request.webpackJsonp.../../../http/@angular/http.es5.js.Request.getBody (http.es5.js:1748)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.es5.js:1275)
    at Observable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
    at Observable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
    at CatchOperator.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operators/catchError.js.CatchOperator.call (catchError.js:79)
    at Observable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:157)
    at MapOperator.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call (map.js:56)
    at Observable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:157)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You need to JSON.stringify your data before you pass to Http POST

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

**full function**

```
editProfileData(data, branchId) {
        console.log('request data', data);
        return this.http.post(this.config.STORE_KEY + '/public/api/business/changerequest/' + 
                 this.userDetails.roleid + '/' + branchId, JSON.stringify(data))
                 .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                 .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

I hope this will resolve your problem. If you have any issues let me know.

Comment: Thanks, @Suvethan Nantha

Answer (score 0):

it was my mistake
i wrote
timezone: this.profileEditForm.controls.timeZone,

instead of 
timezone: this.profileEditForm.controls.timeZone.get('zone').value

so timezone value sending as formgroup